# Buffer Overflow Problem

Tags: c, windows-7, buffer-overflow

I am trying to run a buffer overflow example to run some code, but the problem is that when I try to run the code just to get a buffer overflow, Windows throws a prompt up stating "Program has stopped working, Windows is checking for a solution to the program. So when I try to make sure it just has a overflow by one byte. The program just runs, but doesn't pause the command window in order for me to see the segmentation fault error address. Which to my understanding I would need in order to change it and make it run my desired window as the passed parameter.Here is the simple program.

```
#define BUF_LEN 5

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

char buf[BUF_LEN];

if (argc > 1)
{
 strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
}
 return 0;
 printf(buf);
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What's the length of argv[1]?

Comment: I make it at least more than buff, for example buff is now 5 in this program, so I make it "AAAAAAAA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that buffer overflow behavior is not standardized - your example may refer to an older version of Windows, which still printed an error address, or to a completely different operating system.

Additionally, not all buffer overflows cause the program to crash - it depends on what data is written where. For small buffer overflows, you may be overwriting only some other local variables or padding space, instead of anything essential for the program execution (like the function return address).

Comment: this actually answered the question

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation faults are just one manifestation of undefined behaviour. There is really nothing that guarantees you that the OS will give you any information about what went wrong here.

You don't need the address in order to diagnose the segfault anyway. There is exactly one thing that can cause a buffer overflow here and you know exactly what it is: the strcpy() call.

Assuming you must use C, the fix is to use strncpy() instead.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but if I read the OP right, he intentionally wants to cause a buffer overflow for exercise purposes.

Comment: I know that strncpy() will prevent the buffer overflow. but I am trying to create an exmaple to show what I can make happen by causing one with some shellcode, but I assummed I need the seg fault address to do that

Comment: This doesnt answer my question at all but yet it has two votes?

Comment: @Eric: What part of "undefined behavior" didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define BUF_LEN 5

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

char buf[BUF_LEN];

if (argc > 1)
{
 strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
}

 printf(buf);
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

`return 0;` goes in the end. Otherwise the program execution stops there.

Comment: thanks,now it prints the buf but it still runs into the same problem by not outputing an error address.. Isn't this what I should get

Comment: I dont think it is supposed to print an error address. more like a "SegFault" Thingy.

Comment: it doesnt print anything.. it prints the buf like there was no error, but when i press the any key to continue, it runs a Windows prompt load issue error I mentioned above and then closes

Comment: I make it at least more than buff, for example buff is now 5 in this program, so I make it "AAAAAAAA"

Comment: Well you just end up writing on memory you shouldn't, thats all, and its not good. nothing really bad will happen unless you overwrite something usefull.

Comment: @Muggen- exactly, which is my question, I was trying to find out what should I actually be passing in to know what address to overwrite and cause it to invoke a pass parameter thats a program

Comment: You cant know what address you gonna overwrite, unless you printf() the memory location of the buf. if the buf has size 5 then the last compile-time allocated byte exists at buf+5 (buf is the memory loc of the first index of the array), from buf+6 and afterwards it illegal to write. what do you mean "cause it to invoke a pass parameter thats a program" ?

Comment: If you mean : On Buffer Overflow : Execute another program then you need to search different stuff. try-catch is called and is C++ only. I dont know if there is another method for Raw C.

Comment: @Muggen- I mean instead of passing in AAAAAA, I want to pass in for example ".text 
.global main 
main: 
    mov $0x68732f6e69622fff, %rbx 
    shr $0x8, %rbx 
    push %rbx 
    mov %rsp, %rdi 
    xor %rsi, %rsi 
    xor %rdx, %rdx 
    xor %rax, %rax 
    add $0x3b, %rax 
    syscall 
" that would do things, locally just to prove the vulnerability of buffer overflow

Comment: @Muggen- what do you mean "try-catch is called?

Comment: Sorry I cant help you with what you mean, cause I dont know the answer. pseudo-Shell injection is not possible that way if I understand you well. The system will see this a a String. Not as new Code in the program.

Comment: Try-Catch is a way to catch exceptional ways you cant predict on code. For example here : In case a buffer overflow happens, an exception is thrown and is catch()-ed somewhere else and you do stuff to save the system. but I think I do not think it is what you need or want. I understood wrong.

Comment: @Muggen- Oh you talking about catching exceptions.I understand that, but I am not trying to save the program

Comment: yes now its clear. you cant introduce new code to compiled things. maybe you could look into process injection or stuff like that but I have no idea....

Answer (score 0):

On compiling use "gcc -fno-stack-protector -o out filename.c",
because gcc contains inbuilt stack protector and u have to remove it.
-fno-stack-protector will remove the protector function from gcc